# C# ToolStrip Insert Standard Menu Standard Icons Location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, icons

I found this post [VS-2010_Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238151/net-toolstrip-menustrip-focus-issues) on stackoverflow regarding the location of the standard icons used when you create a toolstrip and "insert standard items" like New, Print, Cut, Paste, etc in the toolstrip.

But perhaps this has changed for VS 2012 as I cannot locate these icons.  Where do you find the icons in VS 2012 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is missing in Visual studio 2012 and you can manually download it from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825